# Transition from normalized to normal stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have a list of normalized stacked bar charts. When the user clicks on the bar chart it is supposed to zoom in and transition to a not normalized version of the same bar chart.

I got everything working except for the transition.
Check out the code: http://jsfiddle.net/adius/tgC2m

I don't get why it's not scaling it properly but instead even shrinking it.
When I change the order to zoom from non-normalized to a normalized version it also works in the first place but messes up the transition. So the charts themselves are OK, but the transition is not. Is it even possible to transition from `.offset('expand')` to `.offset('zero')` and vice versa?

Any help would be really appreciated as my deadline is approaching really fast! ^^